# react-native start --non-interactive choose platform

Tags: react-native, build, react-native-cli

I'm trying to run `react-native start` in Github Workflow CI, so I need to use `react-native start --non-interactive`, but how do I specify the platform to be `iOS` or `android`?

I took a look at the [README](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-plugin-metro/README.md), but there's no `--platform` option for `start`.